# Kusto query could not be parsed at 'sys'

Tags: database, azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

While executing this query on the log analytics tool of the azure database

```
SELECT * FROM sys.event_log
```

Got the error as

> Query could not be parsed at 'sys' on line [1,14]
>
> Token: sys Line: 1 Position: 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Explorer support SQL however you need to escape it like this:

```
select * from [sys.event_log]
```

Azure Log Analytics does not support the SQL language and you have to use the "Kusto Query Language". You first need to find the table that has the data you are looking for and then use the "Kusto Query Language" to find the relevant data. There are many sample queries when you begin to use Azure Log Analytics.